# AngularJS: Triangular three way binding -- Project Structure

Tags: angularjs, structure

I am currently working out an admin interface with a Live Preview and I am still not 100% on how to structure it properly.

My page basically consists out of two parts. The **Admin Interface** and the **Live Preview**. Obviously, the Admin Interface fills some variables with data and the Live Preview displays this.

Therefore, the Admin Interface needs to bind variables, that the Live Preview will bind for reading.

Furthermore, the Live Preview in the end (if possible) should be re-used as the final product that displays a set of information. All it does is display a single JSON file that is received from the server (when in product mode) and in case of the Live Preview it will need to update the data Live as its edited.

*One more note: Both, the Live Preview and the Admin Interface consist of elements like directives again and parts of the Admin Interface need to be loaded dynamically by having a user add a page with a certain type of content.*

After researching how modules are handled I came up with the following:

- Live Preview is a Module
- Admin Interface is a Module
- My page includes both modules

Both of them should be connected to something central that provides the ability of editing the data (bound variables?) and reading the data so its updated live.

Ideally, this would be a service, so later on when loading the "Live Preview" as an actual product, can just use the same kind of service which in this case provides the information from our Database instead of a variable in its scope.

Is this a good approach? Is there a way to have a service that on the one hand side can be edited lively like in a two way binding so that my live preview can also pick it up? Is there something I can use instead of the services, like a controller? How should I go on about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing everything right.  I don't think that it is relevant as to whether the preview and admin panel are their own modules or contained within one.  You will find people using module seperation in a wide variety of ways within their Angular apps.

What I think you said that is important and correct is to connect the preview and admin panel via a Service.  Other methods of connecting these two (i.e. $rootScope) are costly and bad practice.

If you will be re-using live preview in many locations of your application I would wrap it in a directive.

You should feel confident in your approach, it's a good one.